# Foreign key column update

Tags: oracle, database-trigger, referential-integrity

There are two tables:

```
tblInvestType(Parent table) and
tblInvestTypeComp(Child table)
```

The column `tblInvestTypeComp.type_code` is a foreign key referencing `tblInvestType.type_code`.

How can I create a trigger such that whenever there is any update in the values of the parent table's (`tblInvestType`) `type_code` column, the same is reflected to the child table's (`tblInvestTypeComp`) `type_code` column?

Note: All this is in Oracle.

Comment: Can anybody please help on this on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that i got:

```
create or replace trigger tblInvestType_update_type_code
after update of type_code on tblInvestType
for each row
begin
update tblInvestTypeComp
set type_code = :new.type_code
where type_code = :old.type_code;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following

```
set constraint <constraint name> deferred;
update primary key ...
update foreign key column to match the updated primary key....
commit;
```

to do this the foreign key must be defined as deferrable

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you exactly want to say,for example what is meant by '...' after primary key?

Answer (score 0):

This is poor design. Primary keys should be immutable. But given you  have a requirement here is a solution:

```
Create trigger upd_trg after update on tblInvestType
 for each row
Begin
    Update tblInvestTypeComp
    Set type_code =:new.type_code
    Where type_code =:old.type_code;
End;
```

Comment: This is partially correct ,but after a lot of searching i have found the answer which i have commented.
Just one thing i wanted to ask ,why is this a poor design?Doessn't the foreign key always refers to the primary key of a table and the change in the primary key of the table reflects in the foreign key if we use On update cascade in SQL.
I assume it is a general practice.

Comment: It's poor design because the primary **should not change**.

Comment: okay.But then, what is the point of having **on update cascade** for foreign keys which refer to the primary key of another table.

Comment: Well Oracle doesn't support that, which is why you need a trigger to do it. I know some other DBMS products do support it, mainly because they were shaped by developers who weren't interested in the finer details of data modeling, who just wanted to get on and do stuff, and they'd deal with the mess later. Or rather somebody else would get lumbered with sorting out the mess.

Comment: okay.I got your point.
But one last thing,oracle has on delete cascade,but it is not a poor design because it deals with completely eliminating the data(Primary key value as well as foreign key value)instead of updating it.Am i correct in saying this?